# Golang group and merge by value in goroutine

Tags: go

I'm new in go and tried to populate slice data by same values in GO.
Refer to the following example

```
input struct {
  ID string `json:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Image string `json:"image"`
}

output struct {
  ID    string `json:"id"`
  Name  string `json:"name"`
  Image []img `json:"image"`
}

img struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Width  int  `json:"width"`
  Height int  `json:"height"`
}

input = [{
        "id": 10,
        "name": "product 10",
        "image": {"name": "https://i.imgur.com/eKSk6Fq.jpg"}
    }, {
        "id": 10,
            "name": "product 10",
            "image": {"name": "https://i.imgur.com/np1wmxw.jpg"}
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "name": "product 11",
            "image": {"name": "https://i.imgur.com/jlFgGpe.jpg"}
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "name": "product 11",
            "image": {"name": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsj2.jpg"}
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "name": "product 11",
            "image": {"name": "https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpg"}
    }]

// expected output
output = [{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "product 10",
    "image": [{
        "name": "https://i.imgur.com/eKSk6Fq.jpg",
        "width": 900,
        "height": 600
    }, {
        "name": "https://i.imgur.com/np1wmxw.jpg",
        "width": 600,
        "height": 600
    }]
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "product 11",
    "image": [{
        "name": "https://i.imgur.com/jlFgGpe.jpg",
        "width": 639,
        "height": 700
    }, {
        "name": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsj2.jpg",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 960
    }, {
        "name": "https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpg",
        "width": 540,
        "height": 405
    }]
}]
```

I would like to group `input` to a new slice based on the same `ID`,
so the result `output` would be new slice of new struct with grouped `image` with same `ID`.

- H̶o̶w̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶c̶h̶i̶e̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶o̶u̶t̶p̶u̶t̶`̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶G̶O̶?  update: got the answer from Peter Eichelsheim
- Also, if I had to ge image size in the `input` with http.get and want to use goroutine, how would I achieve the result? since my last code here [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w2awSWUILS-) not achieving the correct output (always get the last input)

note: I don't know why I get null in go playground, but in my laptop the result is: [{"id":11,"name":"product 11","image":[{"name":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDsj2.jpg","width":1280,"height":960}]}]

In PHP, I would do something below to achieve the intended `output`.

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($output[$value["id"]])) {
                $output[$value["id"]] = [
                    "id" => $value["id"],
                    "name" => $value["name"],
                    "image" => [],
                ];
            }

            $get = getimagesize($value["image"]["name"]);
            if ($get) {
                $width  = isset($get[0]) ? $get[0] : 0;
                $height = isset($get[1]) ? $get[1] : 0;
            }

            $output[$value["id"]]["image"][$key] = [
                "name" => $value["image"]["name"],
                "width" => $width,
                "height" => $height,
            ];

            $output[$value["id"]]["image"] = array_values($output[$value["id"]]["image"]);
}

$output = array_values($output);
$json = json_encode($output, true);

echo $json;
```

Thanks

Comment: :D I've had to answer a similar interview question long ago and far away, especially the bit about fetching images using routines that you've since added to your question :D

Using SO to blag your way to an interview... naughty!

Answer (score 1):

Here a little sample with sample json input, using map[int]output to club images into the same product ID.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type input struct {
    ID    int `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Image img    `json:"image"`
}

type output struct {
    ID    int `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Image []img  `json:"image"`
}

type img struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    var jsoninput = []byte(`
    [{
        "id": 10,
        "name": "product 10",
        "image": {"name": "image 10a"}
    }, {
        "id": 10,
            "name": "product 10",
            "image": {"name": "image 10b"}
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "name": "product 11",
            "image": {"name": "image 11a"}
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "name": "product 11",
            "image": {"name": "image 11b"}
    }, {
        "id": 11,
            "name": "product 11",
            "image": {"name": "image 11c"}
    }]`)

    var inputs []input

    err := json.Unmarshal(jsoninput, &inputs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("could not Unmarshal:", err)
    }

    var outputlist = make(map[int]output)

    for _, inp := range inputs {
        outputlist[inp.ID] = output{inp.ID, inp.Name, append(outputlist[inp.ID].Image, inp.Image)}
    }

    var outputs []output

    for _, outp := range outputlist{
        outputs = append(outputs,outp)
    }

    jsonoutput, err := json.Marshal(outputs)

    fmt.Println(string(jsonoutput))
}
```

Comment: top-tip: `var outputs []output`, you know how big the slice will be (`len(outputlist)`), so you can allocate the required memory up-front instead of relying on golang reallocating `cap(output) * 2` every time you exceed `2^N` elements by writing: `outputs := make([]output, 0, len(outputlist)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works for my previous result. I already updated my question, would be grateful if you have solution for my second problem above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs []input // assuming the json has been unmarshalled correctly

outs := make(map[int]output)

// this will create a map, keyed by id, values are groups of inputs
for _, input := range inputs {

    out, exists := outs[input.ID]
    if !exists {
        out = output{
            ID: input.ID,
            Name: input.Name,
        }
    }

   out.Image = append(out.Image, img{Name: input.Name})
}

output := make([]output, len(outs))
var idx int
for key, out := range outs {
    output[idx] = out
    idx++
}
```

Comment: first loop doesn't seem to use `idx`, so should be `for _, input := range inputs`. Also: `outs := map[int]output{}` is shorter to write

Comment: "shorter to write" is certainly preference, but I take the first point. Making edits

Comment: Well, it's 4 characters shorter, so it's objectively shorter. But preference is a valid argument in this case